# Using Array results in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I have the following query:

```
$query_q_pass = sprintf("SELECT * FROM answers INNER JOIN users WHERE a_id = %s and answers.user_id = users.user_id");
$q_pass = mysql_query($query_q_pass, $cd) or die(mysql_error());
$row_q_pass = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_pass);
```

Now the **answers** table from above query has a row **brand_url** which has many different values separated with commas, e.g. **dell, microsoft, hp,** ...

What I want to do is select all those values from the **brand_url** row and add them in another query where I will extract all brands that exist inside **brand_url**. This is the other query:

```
$query_conn_brands = 'SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_url = 'VALUE FROM ABOVE QUERY'';
$conn_brands = mysql_query($query_conn_brands, $cd) or die(mysql_error());
$row_conn_brands = mysql_fetch_assoc($conn_brands);
$totalRows_conn_brands = mysql_num_rows($conn_brands);
```

I tried many diferent ways using arrays but all I get is all results from the **brands** table.  This is my last unsuccessful try:

```
$brand_pass_ids = $row_q_pass['brand_id'];
$array = array($brand_pass_ids,);

$query_conn_brands = 'SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_url IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $array)) . ')';
$conn_brands = mysql_query($query_conn_brands, $cd) or die(mysql_error());
$row_conn_brands = mysql_fetch_assoc($conn_brands);
$totalRows_conn_brands = mysql_num_rows($conn_brands);
```

From the above example all I get is ALL results from **brands** table and not only those that exist inside **answers** table.  I really hope someone will help me with this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's failing is because your query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_url IN (dell,microsoft,hp)
```

There are string values, and so they must be handled as strings. Try:

```
implode(",",array_map(function($a) {return json_encode($a);},$array))
```

Although encoding as JSON may seem crazy, it's actually a good choice here. Strings are wrapped in quotes and escaped as needed, numbers are left as they are, and `null` is also handled correctly.

**EDIT:** For older versions of PHP that don't support anonymous functions:

```
implode(",",array_map(create_function('$a','return json_encode($a);'),$array));
```

Comment: With that code I am getting following error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in Z:\www\answers\q.php on line 86

Comment: yes, when I have only one results inside brand_url row I get the results, however when I have more then one e.g. dell, microsoft, hp,... I am not getting any results

Comment: @Kolink: why not just `array_map('json_encode', $array)`? The manually created function gets you nothing and wastes memory.

Comment: @DCoder Because I got mixed up between `array_map` and `array_walk` with regards to how many arguments are passed to the callback. That said, this way allows for easy adding of further parameters to `json_encode`.

Comment: @Kolink So how to make it work if there are more then one results inside brands_id row?

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to ***`N`*** if the string ***`str`*** is in the string list ***`strlist`*** consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “`,`” characters. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html), the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns `0` if ***`str`*** is not in ***`strlist`*** or if ***`strlist`*** is the empty string. Returns `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“`,`”) character.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
>         -> 2
> ```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM brands WHERE FIND_IN_SET(brand_url, ?)
```

But you could join your queries together if so desired:

```
SELECT *
FROM   answers
  JOIN users  USING (user_id)
  JOIN brands ON FIND_IN_SET(brands.brand_url, answers.brand_url)
WHERE a_id = %s
```